# android openGL ES 2.0 use Frame buffer to render texture twice,but the result is black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I wanted to use openGL to blur a picture.First I created a frame buffer and a texture.And then use glFramebufferTexture2D.the first drawElement is to blur the vertical orientation. the code is :

```
public boolean renderFrameBuffText(){
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb, 0);
    // Bind the framebuffer
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    generateFrameBuffTexture();
    // specify texture as color attachment
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,       
    GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture[0], 0);
    // check status
    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        return false;
    return true;
}
 private void generateFrameBuffTexture(){
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, frameTexture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture[0]);
    // parameters - we have to make sure we clamp the textures to the edges
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20
            .GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, null);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            frameTexture[0], 0);
}
public void activeFrameBuffer() {
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, this.texW, this.texH);
}
```

In onDrawFrame method,first I get the default frame buffer of system,and then generate and render my own frame buffer.Bind the texture of the picture which it would be shown. :

```
 GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 if (hwFrameBuffer == null){
        GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, displayFrameBuf,0);

        IntBuffer dims = IntBuffer.allocate(4);
        GLES20.glGetIntegerv( GLES20.GL_VIEWPORT, dims);
         fbWidth = dims.get(2);
         fbHeight = dims.get(3);

        hwFrameBuffer = new HWFrameBuffer(fbWidth,fbHeight);
        hwFrameBuffer.renderFrameBuffText();

    }
    hwFrameBuffer.activeFrameBuffer();
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureData0);

    //set data of the shader
     .......

   GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
            drawListBuffer);
```

Then I change current buffer to the system buffer. and render the texture in horizontal orientation I had generated to show the blur picture.but I got a black screen

```
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, displayFrameBuf[0]);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, fbWidth, fbHeight);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, hwFrameBuffer.frameTexture[0]);

  //set data of the shader
     .......

 GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
            drawListBuffer);
```